# How to handle missing NaNs for machine learning in python

Tags: python, pandas, machine-learning, missing-data

**How to handle missing values in datasets before applying machine learning algorithm??.**

I noticed that it is not a smart thing to drop missing NAN values. I usually do interpolate (compute mean) using pandas and fill it up the data which is kind of works and improves the classification accuracy but may not be the best thing to do.

Here is a very important question. **What is the best way to handle missing values in data set?**

For example if you see this dataset, only 30% has original data.

```
Int64Index: 7049 entries, 0 to 7048
Data columns (total 31 columns):
left_eye_center_x            7039 non-null float64
left_eye_center_y            7039 non-null float64
right_eye_center_x           7036 non-null float64
right_eye_center_y           7036 non-null float64
left_eye_inner_corner_x      2271 non-null float64
left_eye_inner_corner_y      2271 non-null float64
left_eye_outer_corner_x      2267 non-null float64
left_eye_outer_corner_y      2267 non-null float64
right_eye_inner_corner_x     2268 non-null float64
right_eye_inner_corner_y     2268 non-null float64
right_eye_outer_corner_x     2268 non-null float64
right_eye_outer_corner_y     2268 non-null float64
left_eyebrow_inner_end_x     2270 non-null float64
left_eyebrow_inner_end_y     2270 non-null float64
left_eyebrow_outer_end_x     2225 non-null float64
left_eyebrow_outer_end_y     2225 non-null float64
right_eyebrow_inner_end_x    2270 non-null float64
right_eyebrow_inner_end_y    2270 non-null float64
right_eyebrow_outer_end_x    2236 non-null float64
right_eyebrow_outer_end_y    2236 non-null float64
nose_tip_x                   7049 non-null float64
nose_tip_y                   7049 non-null float64
mouth_left_corner_x          2269 non-null float64
mouth_left_corner_y          2269 non-null float64
mouth_right_corner_x         2270 non-null float64
mouth_right_corner_y         2270 non-null float64
mouth_center_top_lip_x       2275 non-null float64
mouth_center_top_lip_y       2275 non-null float64
mouth_center_bottom_lip_x    7016 non-null float64
mouth_center_bottom_lip_y    7016 non-null float64
Image                        7049 non-null object
```

Comment: "*What is the best way to handle missing values in data set?*" I would argue that the answer to this question is both situation specific, and opinion based.

Comment: You can either drop the rows that have any missing values but this may reduce performance, or set the missing values to some value that doesn't affect the prediction but this may still skew your model if you have many missing values, it really depends. You can use the mean/median but you will have to measure the performance of all approaches and see what is best, it depends on whether there is any value in those features and what model you selet

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
What is the best way to handle missing values in data set?
```

There is NO best way, each solution/algorithm has their own pros and cons (and you can even mix some of them together to create your own strategy and tune the related parameters to come up one best satisfy your data, there are many research/papers about this topic).

For example, **Mean Imputation** is quick and simple, but it would underestimate the variance and the distribution shape is distorted by replacing NaN with the mean value, while **KNN Imputation** might not be ideal in a large data set in terms of time complexity, since it iterate over all the data points and perform calculation for each NaN value, and the assumption is that NaN attribute is correlated with other attributes.

```
How to handle missing values in datasets before applying machine learning algorithm??
```

In addition to *mean imputation* you mention, you could also take a look at *K-Nearest Neighbor Imputation* and *Regression Imputation*, and refer to the powerful [Imputer](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.Imputer.html) class in [scikit-learn](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/) to check existing APIs to use.

**KNN Imputation**

Calculate the mean of k nearest neighbors of this NaN point.

**Regression Imputation**

A regression model is estimated to predict observed values of a variable based on other variables, and that model is then used to impute values in cases where that variable is missing.

[Here](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/preprocessing.html#imputation-of-missing-values) links to scikit's '*Imputation of missing values'* section. 
I have also heard of [Orange](http://orange.biolab.si/docs/latest/reference/rst/Orange.feature.imputation.html) library for imputation, but haven't had a chance to use it yet.

Answer (score 2):

There's no single best way to deal with missing data. The most rigorous approach is to model the missing values as additional parameters in a probabilistic framework like PyMC. This way you'll get a distribution over possible values, instead of just a single answer. Here's an example of dealing with missing data using PyMC: http://stronginference.com/missing-data-imputation.html

If you really want to plug those holes with point estimates, then you're looking to perform "imputation". I'd steer away from simple imputation methods like mean-filling since they really butcher the joint distribution of your features. Instead, try something like [softImpute](https://web.stanford.edu/~hastie/swData/softImpute/vignette.html) (which tries you infer the missing value via low-rank approximation). The original version of softImpute is written for R but I've made a Python version (along with other methods like kNN imputation) here: https://github.com/hammerlab/fancyimpute