# Handling Missing data in column with Boolean Values(1,0) in Python

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, numpy, data-science

I am performing a data cleansing job with Python wherein i am stuck with data having columns with missing data(which are of Booleans values)

Example: df=[1,0,1,0,NaN,1,0,NaN)

I have Tried *df.fillna(df.mean())* but this will give me mean of 1's and 0's in place of "NaN".
Without handling this, analysis will not be completed.
Please advise.

Comment: What is desired output?

Comment: I have to handle this "NaN" values as i have multiple columns like this which has missing values, should i eliminate these rows  or any way to address this data issue

Comment: I think jezreal is asking if you want the NaN values replaced with a value in particular. If you want to remove rows with NaN then you should look at [dropna](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.dropna.html)

Comment: It seems it is a bit [complicated](http://stackoverflow.com/q/27824954/2901002), unfortunately I cannot help you.

Comment: Idea - maybe post question to [stats.stackexchange.com](https://stats.stackexchange.com/) if no answer long time

Comment: If you want to use some metric to "predict" what the missing values ought to be, you would have to provide a _lot_ more information and data. No one can tell you how to predict what two null values should be in an array of 8 elements, only offer general concepts which would make this question too broad.

Comment: This is called Imputation. If you want the values to be from only [0, 1], then you can use the "median" or most_frequent" values from it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think rolling might solve this that will take the maximum in a window of 2 :

```
df=pd.DataFrame([1,0,1,0,np.nan,1,0,np.nan])
```

`df.fillna(0).rolling(window=2,min_periods=1).max()`

Comment: It really worked Thanks a ton..:-) can you please explain the logic, now there are no missing values but want to understand the logic

Comment: 1- fill all NaN values with 0.
2- take the window of the current row and 1 row above.
3- calculate the maximum value in each window.
Please note that the resulting dataframe should be used only to fill the NaN values as it might overwrite some non NaN values

Comment: If we are overwriting the values which are non empty as well then, which is wrong is'nt, please advise, without touching existing values cant we just assign values like this only for missing data. Thanks

Comment: this would be the complete solution `df.loc[np.isnan(df[0])==True] = df.fillna(0).rolling(window=2,min_periods=1).max().loc[df[np.isnan(df[0])].index].values`