# How to handle missing numerical features when using Spark MLlib Decision Trees?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-mllib, feature-extraction

How do I handle a missing numerical feature when using Decision Trees in Spark MLlib?

I am considering replacing the missing feature with the mean of the other values, however I'm not sure what's the impact on the model quality. Does Spark MLlib provide any support for this common issue?

Answer (score 1):

Every DataFrame can take advantage of the DataFrameNaFunctions which can `drop` the offending record (not the whole column), `fill` which can fill the offending datum with static "dummy data" or `replace` which can replace the offending datum with specified data.

https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.1.1/api/scala/#org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameNaFunctions

```
scala> df.na
res20: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameNaFunctions = org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameNaFunctions@e7e9006

scala> df.na.
drop   fill   replace
```

Comment: and what strategy would you recommend among the 3? How about filling/replacing with mean values?

Comment: That is a question worthy of its own answer [and discussion]... Here's a relevant discussion in python/pandas: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27824954/how-to-handle-missing-nans-for-machine-learning-in-python#27825523

Comment: I don't think any of these 3 are as good as treating NULL/missing as a special value. In other words, the tree should split on NULL values separately from other numeric splits.